# Rapid desktop screen capture on Windows

Tags: windows, screen-capture

I want to capture the desktop screen image on Windows.

I know about the CreateCompatibleDC and CreateCompatibleBitmap... functions in C++ but it they are very slow. I need a more rapid method that does a screen capture suitable for real-time updates. In Linux I could use Xlib functions, for example. Are there any similar high-speed or system-level screencap functions for Windows?

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 8 (and later) there is native API: [Desktop Duplication API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487(v=vs.85).aspx)

For Windows 7 (and earlier) you may consider using a mirror driver. For example, [the DFMirage driver](http://www.demoforge.com/dfmirage.htm)

Comment: Does desktop duplication api work at the login prompt & lock screen?